# Observable object array doesn't work in a pipe

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular2-observables, angular-pipe

i'm trying to make an autocompletion method which search User information from a service.
first i create a method which call the service back and return an Observable of UtilisateurCreationDto[]:

```
   autoCompleteDuplication(duplicated_name :string): Observable<UtilisateurCreationDto[]>{
        console.log("in in");

        return this.userCreationService.autoCompleteDuplication(duplicated_name);
    }
```

*the model UtilisateurCreationDto is simple class with properties.
the methode is called as bellow :

```
search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
    text$.pipe(
      debounceTime(200),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      map(term => term.length < 2 ? []
        : this.autoCompleteDuplication(term).subscribe(data=>{

        data.filter(v => v.nom.toLowerCase().startsWith(term.toLocaleLowerCase()))
        })
        )
    );
```

on the html template, i call the search on a [ngbTypeahead] :

```
      <input id="typeahead-config" type="text" [(ngModel)]="duplication_name" 
        [ngbTypeahead]="search"
        />
```

when i try to enter the text on the field of search i get this error :

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

do you have an idea why the return type UtilisateurCreationDto[] is not working with my implementation ? knowing that is works fine if i change the call of service with a static string[].

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You should use `SwitchMap` instead of `Map` in that case in `pipe`.

```
search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
    text$.pipe(
      debounceTime(200),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap(term => term.length < 2 ? of([])
        : this.autoCompleteDuplication(term).pipe(map(data=>{

         return data.filter(v => v.nom.toLowerCase().startsWith(term.toLocaleLowerCase()))
        }))
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

i suggest that you refactor your search method like the following, and use switchMap instead

```
search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
text$.pipe(
  filter((trm) => trm.trim().length > 2),
  debounceTime(200),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  switchMap(term => this.autoCompleteDuplication(term).pipe(
    map((data)=> data.filter(v => v.nom.toLowerCase().startsWith(term.toLocaleLowerCase()))
   ))
);
```